# Selecting elements by xpath

Tags: python, xpath, web-scraping

I have this page
https://www.punters.com.au/form-guide/2020-01-14/

There are races names like Spendthrift Australia Park, Dalby and etc.
I would like to find a way to extract races for certain country. For example, my script should take races in Australia. But I don't know how to make right xpath to that races. Because number of races is each time different. 
Or for any other country. 
I just need correct xpath

```
from selenium import webdriver

country = input('Enter country name (ex Australia, New Zealand..): ')
driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get("https://www.punters.com.au/form-guide/2020-01-14/")
for i in driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//tr[./td/img[@title='Australia']]//following-sibling::tr/td[@class='upcoming-race__td upcoming-race__meeting-name upcoming-races__show-pdfs']//following-sibling::td[1]/a".format(country)):
    print(i.text)

driver.close()
```

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: Well, I tryed with xpath selecting the data between two sibling tags. Bun unsucesfully, and it can not work for the last one. Because there is different div at the end.  @JackFleeting

Comment: You should edit your question and post what you have tried; otherwise, some people may vote to close your question.

Comment: I added some selenium code, so it is easy to see @JackFleeting

Comment: As you can see, I have all 10 urls, I want just urls under Australia.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to select target nodes with one "magic xpath", here it is:

```
from selenium import webdriver

country = 'South Africa'
driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get("https://www.punters.com.au/form-guide/2020-01-14/")

xpath = f"//tr[preceding-sibling::tr[contains(@class, 'upcoming-race__row--country')]/td/img[@title='{country}']][position()<=(count(//tr[preceding-sibling::tr[contains(@class, 'upcoming-race__row--country')]/td/img[@title='{country}']])-count(//tr[preceding-sibling::tr[preceding-sibling::tr[contains(@class, 'upcoming-race__row--country')]/td/img[@title='{country}'] and contains(@class, 'upcoming-race__row--country')][1]])-count(//tr[preceding-sibling::tr[contains(@class, 'upcoming-race__row--country')]/td/img[@title='{country}'] and contains(@class, 'upcoming-race__row--country')][1]))]/td[1]"
found_nodes = driver.find_elements_by_xpath(xpath)

driver.close()
```

***Let's describe what this XPath does on example with New Zealand:***

*I will alias blocks of XPath for better readability of result's concept at the end.*

**1.** First part is about finding where to start - lets find node with New Zealand header  *(let's alias it as TARGET_XPATH)*:

```
`//tr[preceding-sibling::tr[contains(@class, 'upcoming-race__row--country')]/td/img[@title='New Zealand']]`
```

**2.** Now we need to limit found results to single country only.
The best choice for this operation in current case i know - "position" operator. 
We must provide position of last useful element (before first "trashy") in our results. Let's calculate it:

```
`(count(//tr[preceding-sibling::tr[contains(@class, 'upcoming-race__row--country')]/td/img[@title='New Zealand']])-count(//tr[preceding-sibling::tr[preceding-sibling::tr[contains(@class, 'upcoming-race__row--country')]/td/img[@title='New Zealand'] and contains(@class, 'upcoming-race__row--country')][1]])-count(//tr[preceding-sibling::tr[contains(@class, 'upcoming-race__row--country')]/td/img[@title='New Zealand'] and contains(@class, 'upcoming-race__row--country')][1]))`
```

Here we counting three types of elements:

a. Count of nodes after our country header node *(naming as COUNT_TOTALS)*:

`count(//tr[preceding-sibling::tr[contains(@class, 'upcoming-race__row--country')]/td/img[@title='New Zealand']])`

b. Count of nodes after first "trashy" node *(naming as COUNT_AFTER_TRASHY_HEADER)*:

`count(//tr[preceding-sibling::tr[preceding-sibling::tr[contains(@class, 'upcoming-race__row--country')]/td/img[@title='New Zealand'] and contains(@class, 'upcoming-race__row--country')][1]])`

c. And we must check for any "trashy" node, for case when we are searching races for last country in table - it won't has next "trashy" node *(naming as COUNT_TRASHY_HEADER)*:

`count(//tr[preceding-sibling::tr[contains(@class, 'upcoming-race__row--country')]/td/img[@title='New Zealand'] and contains(@class, 'upcoming-race__row--country')][1])`

**3.** Use our count as filter:

```
TARGET_XPATH[position()<=(COUNT_TOTALS - COUNT_AFTER_TRASHY_HEADER - COUNT_TRASHY_HEADER)]
```

Comment: Well, thank you a lot. This is huge xpath,there are probably other ways, but you proved that this can be done on this way. Great job!

Answer (score 0):

Let's try it this way (for Australia only):

```
from selenium import webdriver
import pandas as pd

driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get("https://www.punters.com.au/form-guide/2020-01-14/")

tabs = driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//table')
rows = []
for i in tabs[0].find_elements_by_xpath("//tr[./td/img[@title='Australia']]/following-sibling::tr[position()<5]"):
    row = []
    for dat in i.find_elements_by_xpath('.//td'):        
        row.append(dat.text)
    rows.append(row)
pd.DataFrame(rows)
```

Output (pardon the formatting):

```
             0  1   2   3   4   5   6   7   8   9   10
0   Spendthrift Australia Park  ABD ABD ABD ABD ABD ABD ABD ABD     
1   Dalby   6,2 3,2 8,9,4   8,4,7   10,5,1  ABD 8,9,6   3,6,4   11,9,1  6,1,5
2   Corowa  3,1,4   6,4,3   2,4 2,1,5   2,7,9   12,2,6  3,1,6           
3   Scone   14,9,6  10,1,18 5,3,1   7,2,6   12,6,8  12,2,10 12,7,2
```